# mysql command- disable interactive behavior

Tags: mysql, authentication

I am trying to login to mysql through phpshell with:

```
    mysql -u root -ppw
```

however, the shell waits indefinitely after this command. how do i disable interactive behavior?

Comment: How to make a shell non-interactive? Don't use a shell.  What are you trying to do with mysql? You could probably just issue a query to it.

Comment: i need to login to mysql through the shell. how can i get it to respond to the login command without waiting? is there someway to signal to mysql to not wait?

Comment: it's waiting for you to run a command...  what were you expecting?

Comment: You'll probably see the mysql prompt (mysql>). After that you can enter your commands.

Comment: I don't see a prompt- my shell gets stuck waiting. How do I prevent it from getting stuck?

Comment: I finally figured out the solution: use a batch file

Comment: mysql -u user -p db-name < batch.sql